# Can't get Ext.ux.grid.Search to work in extjs 4.2

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I want to use the search plugin for my grid. An import is needed for the search plugin, which according to the doc i can find is : **Ext.ux.grid.Search**.

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.tree.*',
    'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature',
    'Ext.toolbar.Paging',
    'Ext.ux.grid.Search'
]);
```

Then you just need to add to your plugins in your table, as far as I understand. Like this :

```
plugins: [{
    ptype: 'bufferedrenderer',
        trailingBufferZone: 20,  // Keep 20 rows rendered in the table behind scroll
        leadingBufferZone: 50   // Keep 50 rows rendered in the table ahead of scroll
    },
    new Ext.ux.grid.Search({
        iconCls:'icon-zoom'
        ,readonlyIndexes:['country']
        ,disableIndexes:['pctChange']
        ,minChars:1
        ,autoFocus:true
        ,mode:'local' // to filter on local; for remote add mode:'remote'
        ,width: '50'
    })
],
```

However the error I get is :

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

for the line

> new Ext.ux.grid.Search({

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From the name of the plugin I guess that it is the plugin I've written way back so you may use either old version or a fork.

I have recently updated the plugin for Ext 4.x and also the deployment method is now easy and straightforward as it is distributed as a package recognized by Sencha Cmd.

See it [here](http://extjs.eu/software/ext-grid-search-plugin/).